# Laravel jquery autocomplete data fetching from json are not being displayed in view

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I was setting up the autocomplete function to my project and I think i got the logic well but the datas are not being displayed on the input.

Controller:

```
Public function autoComplete(Request $request) {

    $term = $request->get('term','');

    $queries=DB::table('patients')
    ->where('name','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->select('patients.id','patients.name')
    ->get();

    $results=array();

    foreach ($queries as  $query)
    {
        $results[] = ['id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->name];
    }
    if(count($results))
        return response()->json($results);
    else
        return ['id'=>'','value'=>'No Result Found'];
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('autocomplete',['as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'TestController@autoComplete']);
```

Blade:

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="test">
```

Jquery&ajax inside that blade:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        src = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
        $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: src,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term : request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
        });
    });
```

Spent two days lookin where the problem could be cause there arent showing any errors just no display data in autocomplete input ,
Can it be the scripts conflicts or the jquery didnt implement well , i dont know thats missing here. 
the json response is ok but sending the datas to jquery wit ajax I guess that is not working.

p.s for the front end part im using materializecss library.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution : 
I was missing the styles of jqueryUI:

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" 
   type="text/css">
```

added them inside the blade and now works like a charm! 
Thanks:)